# Assigning Values to Views when using $this->renderScript

Tags: zend-framework

in order to avoid copy/paste, i can use a unique view for different actions, i can do this using one of these ways

```
$this->renderScript('index/index.phtml'); 
$this->view->var = "hello world";
```

or

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer('index');
$this->view->var = "hello world";
```

if i want to use a different controller i have to  use the 1st one, the viewRenderer is ok, but when i use the renderScript it shows nothing like `var` is not defined. how can i assign values to the view script?

index.phtml would be somthing like this

`echo $this->var ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work the way you described it

```php
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
        $this->view->var = 'echo me in any action viewscript and i will show you text';
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
        $this->view->test = 'Don\'t put me here becuase this is not the action that is run';

    }

    public function testAction()
    {
        // action body

        $this->view->test = 'Hello world';
        $this->renderScript('index/index.phtml');
        // or $this->_helper->viewRenderer('index');
    }

}
```

in my view (index.phtml)

i have

```php
<?php echo $this->test;?>
```

When i go to /index/test/ it will show "hello world"...

Also when i do it in another controller it gives me the result

```php
class MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
        $this->view->test = 'Hello world';
        $this->renderScript('index/index.phtml'); 
    }

}
```

Comment: when using a different controller you have to use $this->renderScript('index/index.phtml'); then the problem shows up

Comment: i have no problem when both actions are in one controller

Comment: Ah sorry then i didn't understand your question... brbr let me check something

Comment: i got the problem !! assining values should be be before the renderScript i was assinging them after it, in that case viewRenderer has no problem, but renderScript does!!

Comment: It's always the little things that make it hard :)

Comment: thank you .. :D i really would be happy if i could understand the philosophy of the problem.. :| feel like a machine when i discover these things with try and error.