# Zend default view script name switch

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view, zend-layout

I want to display a mobile view instead of the normal view script.

Let's take for example this action /my_module/my_controller/my_action.

When I call it, based on some headers processing I know that user agent is a mobile device.
Then I set the main layout to be a mobile-specific layout. 
I do that like this and it works fine: `Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('mobile');`

But in my controller or somewhere else I want to override the default view file `my_action.phtml` on something like `my_action_mobile.phtml`.

How that could be done considering that in some of my views I am using the action helper as this: `<?php echo $this->action("index", "index", "items")?>` or is some of my action I have a _forward like this: `$this->_forward("index", "auth", "default");`

I have tried with `setViewSuffix('mobile')` and with several file name variants as: my_action.mobile.phtml, or `setViewSuffix('mobile.phtml')` and the file called my_action.mobile.phtml and others, resulting in a blank page - no error, nothing. ( i have no ideea why because it is set to display the thrown errors )

Also I have tried with contextSwitching but it disables my main layout - i do not want this - and it feels like it does not handles properly the action view helper. ( a view rendered in another )

I would appreciate any suddgestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an awful lot of information on the subject. For starters get youself throught http://static.zend.com/topics/Mobile-web-app-with-ZF.pdf

In a nutshell, you should use ContextSwitch.

1. You create a plugin that defines available contexts and format
   parameter derived from Zend_Http_UserAgent.
2. In controller you describe which actions are eligible for those contexts.
3. Create different views for those actions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to change the view from the controller
`$this->render('actionName')`;

or, alternatively, you can call a view script directly by calling
`$this->renderScript('path/to/viewscript.phtml')`;

You can get more details on the render() and renderScript() methods from [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) .
Check this SO post too [Assigning Values to Views when using $this->renderScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079333/assigning-values-to-views-when-using-this-renderscript)